# подскажите, что такое "??"

Tags: javascript

подскажите ссылку на описание оператора "??", поиск не находит, но в консоле работает как "||"

```js
let v;
console.log(v ?? 5);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator)

Проверяет, является ли левый оператор null или undefined и если это так, то возвращает правый оператор, иначе левый. Отличие от || в том, что второй проверяет логическое выражение false слева.

```js
console.log(false ?? 1)
console.log(false || 1)

console.log(null ?? 1)
console.log(null || 1)
```